# Finding the tangent lines to an implicit curve

Tags: calculus

Let $x \gt 0$. Find the tangent lines to the curve $x^{\sin y} + y^2 - x = (\pi^2)/(4)$ at the points of the intersection of the given curve and the line $x=1$.
I found this result $y=\pm \pi/2$ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{\sin y} +y^2 -x =\frac{\pi^2}{4} $$ When $x=1$, $$1+y^2-1=\frac{\pi^2}{4} \implies y=\pm \frac{\pi}{2} $$

Now differentiate.  $\bigg [(x ^{\sin y} )’ = ( e^{\sin y \ln x} )’ = x^{\sin y}\left ( \frac{\sin y}{x} + \ln x\cos y \frac{dy}{dx} \right) \bigg]$

$$x^{\sin y}\left ( \frac{\sin y}{x} + \ln x\cos y \frac{dy}{dx} \right) +2y\frac{dy}{dx} -1 =0 $$

to readily obtain $y’(1,\pi/2) = 0$ and $y’(1,-\pi/2) = -\frac{2}{\pi}$ and the equations of the tangents:

$$y=\frac{\pi}{2} \\ y+\frac{\pi}{2} = -\frac{2}{\pi} (x-1) $$